# Is marginal product of x1 an increasing or decreasing function of x2?

Tags: economics

Suppose that a firm has the production function $${f(x_1,x_2) = x_1^\frac{1}{2} + x_2^2}$$

I know that you have to find the marginal product for both $x_1$ and $x_2$ and those come out to be $x_1 = \frac{1}{2\sqrt x}$ and $x_2 = 2x_2$

Where do I go from here?

*I should add, the answer to this question is that it's **neither** increasing or decreasing - as verified by my teacher

Answer (score 0):

Your own calculations indicate that the marginal product of $f$  wrt $x_1$ is independent of $x_2$ because the partial of $f$ wrt to $x_1$ doesn't involve $x_2$.